# write and read object array in nodejs with (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm using Node.js with socket.io. I want the client to write a file on server-side like when some client adds a comment.

**My code on server-side**

```
var readcomments=fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'comments.txt'),(e,comment)=> {
    if(e) {
        socket.emit('readcomments',e);
    } else
        comment=JSON.stringify(comment);
        socket.emit('readcomments',comment);
        console.log(comment);
        socket.on('writeComment',(text)=> {
            fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'comments.txt'),
            comment,(e)=> {

        })
    })
})
```

**client-side**

```
socket.on('readcomments',(comments)=> {   
    comments.map((name)=> {
        newarray= array.concat(name.data)
    })

    socket.emit('writeComment',newarray.concat([some object]))
})
```

I know that my code is messed up but can you give me a simple example to add an array that contains objects and read it from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a little bit for redability.

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname,'comments.txt');

const onCommentsRead = (e, value) => {
  if(e) {
    socket.emit('readcomments', e);
  } else {
    const commentsArray = value.toString().split("\n");
    const comments = JSON.stringify(commentsArray);
    socket.emit('readcomments', comments);
    console.log(comments);
    socket.on('writeComment', (text) => onCommenntWrite(text, comments));
  }
}

const onCommenntWrite = (text, comments) => {
  fs.appendFile(filePath, comments);
};

const readcomments= fs.readFile(filePath, onCommentsRead);
```

I don't see any problem in this code, it sends the error if there's one or the content that has been read.

Just notice that you need to get an array by splitting on `\n` if you want to send an array.

Comment: when i use split the object convert to a string

Comment: @GrinningTrout When you split it should create an array, doesn't it?